# Maintain State of Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with the MVC3 pattern.

In a page with 3 tables and when user selects the 1st row and clicks on the edit button to edit, they are redirected to another page.

When they are finished editing and click save,  they are redirected to same page and the first row does not remain selected in the first table.

Comment: what you tried? where is your code?

Comment: Code would be helpful/  this question is very confusing.

Comment: Why people doesn't read few Question on Stackoverflow before posting?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and I am going to assume that English is not the native tongue of the poster, so I do expect mistakes.  I guess that is what editors are for, but you need to first understand the question to edit in the first place.

Comment: Are you able to update your post with code, that would be helpful in understanding your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to find a way to pass that information back to the original page- I guess in the querystring is probably easiest, then you can just check it from your view or use the ViewModel or ViewBag to let you know which row, if any, has been edited.

However, in my experience with MVC3, unless there is a compelling reason to change pages, multi-row page editing is very easy and user-friendly to accomplish using AJAX so the user isn't having to switch between views the whole time. That would avoid this whole problem.

Comment: I would just ignore the 1st paragraph of this answer.. you SHOULD be using AJAX for your problem.  There is a reason jQuery ships with MVC :)

Comment: Technically the first paragraph is where I answer the question, I felt I should include it for form's sake really. As usually happens on SO there was a clear difference between answering the question and solving the problem.

Comment: Agreed and understand.. trying to communicate that any future readers (and this one) should really just do it right.. :)